# How can I make a CanDestroy tool on Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been putting in the command:

```
/give @p iron_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy: ["diamond_ore"]}
```

I've been putting this into a command block. I've repeatedly tried to fix it, change it a little, re-enter it, I even destroyed the command block and tried a new one. Nothing worked. It's been saying the same thing:

```
Line 1, Column 2
Missing: "}" or object member name
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Command Block window]

Comment: What are you doing wrong? I don't know, playing Windows 10 edition? The error has nothing to do with your command. I would suggest filing a bug report, but apparently they don't even look at that, so I guess you have to either switch to an older version where it still worked or wait for the developers to randomly stumble upon the same problem and fix it. Moral of the story: MCPE is evil, use Java Edition.

Comment: try this: /give @p minecraft:iron_pick 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:diamond_ore"]}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 2):

In MCBE, you can not directly use {CanDestroy:["minecraft:diamond_ore"]}.
Use instead:

```
/give @p minecraft:iron_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["diamond_ore"]}}
```

which used a JSON like syntax on that.